# How to customize Navigation Bar of Email Composer in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, ios6

How can I change the image of Bar Button of emailcomposer in iPhone app? I am able to change the image of the Navigation Bar but I also have to change the image of Send and cancel button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8714802/1059705 just see this link, may be helpful but you can change the color of the button in this way   [[yourMailComposeView navigationBar] setTintColor:yourColor];

Answer (score 2):

the composer is presented modally as rootviewcontrolelr of a navigation controller.

If you change properties of UINavigationCar as well UIBarButtonItem  with `appearance`, it should do the trick

```
UIBarButtonItem *barbuttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

if ([barbuttonItem respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) {
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:kUIBarButtonItemTitleColor];
}
```

But keep in mind that this will change all bar button items not only the ones in mail composer.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to limit the style change to just a certain class (`appearanceWhenContainedIn ...`, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257556/ios-5-curious-about-uiappearance

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing them through mailComposeViewController.navigationBar.items, which is an array of the bar items.